# Dell C1760NW linux driver

Tags: linux, drivers, printer

I got a hold of a Dell C1760NW printer, but unfortunately I can't make it work from Linux, specifically Linux Mint 12 Lisa. In theory it supports PCL5, but I haven't had any success with a generic PCL driver.

Anyone had success printing to this type of beast under Linux? How?

Comment: The Dell C1760NW does not support PCL5, it is a GDI (host-based) printer so a PCL5 driver, generic or otherwise, will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this this will probably help you:  http://codefucius.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/getting-dell-c1760nw-color-printer-up.html

Comment: In the meantime I got rid of that Dell printer, but looks like a working solution, thanks.